# Why Tesseract psm config is giving error when run through python subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, tesseract

I am trying to run tesseract through python subprocess using the following code:

```
import subprocess

extract = subprocess.run(['tesseract', 'imCropped.png', 'stdout', '-l', 'eng', '--psm 6'], capture_output=True, text=True)

print(extract.stdout, extract.stderror)
```

But, it throws the following error and doesn't run:

`Error, unknown command line argument '--psm 6'`

When run other combinations (e.g. remove the psm setting but keep the language setting, it runs and gives the output.

When I use the CLI, the following command runs properly and gives output:

```
tesseract imCropped.png stdout -l eng --psm 6
```

What am I doing wrong? Is the psm config setting not supported when used via subprocess?

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks!

PS: The project requires that I dont use pytesseract bindings, which are working fine for the psm config.

Comment: `--psm` and `6` are two separate arguments, so you should pass them as such: `'--psm', '6'`

Comment: oh, yeah! it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Split

> '--psm 6'

to two string.